# DirectoryIndex ignoring index.php

Tags: php, apache, failed-installation, apache2.2

I am trying to setup my Apache2 from scratch, it installed with no modules enabled, or any relavant default configuration for what could be considered a 'web host' (in fact html displayed as text, and PHP files downloaded)

Anyways I have this in my httpd.conf

```
# Default Directory Settings
<Directory />
     DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

index.html seems to work find by default but index.php will not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /home/was/www
    <Directory /home/was/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Options +ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Location /cgi-bin >
        SetHandler cgi-script
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice all the hacks just to get things to work, like PHP. It's annoying.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `AddType` just tells the browser that the type of header that should be send back is `x-httpd-php` for `.php` files. If you need to process the php data that's in those files, try using `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: Oh really? Cause that code comes with PHP out of the box, and with it, PHP works, without it, it doesn't. Turns out the whole problem was the site wasn't enabled. But Apache was still reading parts of the file, and utilizing it, mainly the IP and port listening which made me think it's all working. My friend never told me he never ran `a2ensite` on it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you don't have a site enabled, Apache2 may still load up the file and use some of it's settings.

This file, particularily, declared one of my IPs to use, and forward to a new www document root, on a new port. That was working, even with the site disabled, but the `<directory>` and other settings were *not* working, until I enabled it.

My bad, but weird functionality on Apache2's part.